Terminating differential signals with input and output load
I am trying to terminate a differential pair which has input and output load of 200 Ohms.
(R1 and R5 in the schematic)
In between input and output load, I have two transmission lines and I have modelled them as lossless (50  Ohms). I am assuming for now that there is no coupling between the traces. There is 1:1 transformer between them. Based on Eric Bogatin's book,
Z_diff = 2 * Z_odd , and
Z_comm = 1/2 * Z_even
Now R4 is there to balance common mode noise, but for differential mode,  I have a mixture of parallel and series impedances, and I do not know what values of Z_odd  would be that R2 and R3 are determined. Bogatin's book has only line impedances, and I cannot get my head around it with R1 and R5 in parallel, and there is one 50 Ohms impedance on one side of the transformer .


note that R1 is short-circuited by the input voltage sources, did you intend this, or should they be current sources?

@Neil_UK R1 is there as a constraint  in the design I am analyzing . The only reason I have used V1 and V2 as they are is to create signals which are differential.

Are you aware that V1 and V2, being zero output resistance, short circuit R1, and thus render its value irrelevant in the circuit?

To be honest, I did not see it. I have now changed the circuit to what I am actually working with including 1:1 transformer. Now the 200 Ohm parallel should make more sense, though It was handed to me as a constraint and I do not know much about its impact.

Are you aware that after your addition of the 1:1 transformer to the circuit, V1 and V2 are STILL shortcircuiting R2, rendering its value irrelevant? Does you circuit voltage-drive R2, or does it current-drive it?
